# Equivalent of Cig Kofte restaurants in Georgia

Tags: budget, turkey, georgia-country, local-cuisine, azerbaijan

In Turkey I discovered Cig Kofte restaurants, which have been great for me on my walking/cycling trip. They are very cheap and have reduced my food expenditure by about 3$ per day. In the staff I have found kindred spirits who are often in my exact demographic (late 20s male) and are always interested in what I'm doing (escape from normal life I suppose via long distance walking) and make me feel welcome, and we often bond very easily. It's not unusual for them to offer me their couch for the night as well actually.

Now I am in Georgia, and then perhaps Azerbaijan. Do Georgia or Azerbaijan have an equivalent genre of very cheap eateries which have a very small number of friendly staff and a very casual atmosphere? (One American resident in Batumi said there is some kind of "Soviet Buffet" in the city, which he thought might be the similar concept. I don't know if anybody knows what this could be.)

Comment: Are you sure if the type of eatery is relevant? I have also bicycled at least through the European part of Turkey and was almost everywhere approached by curious locals wondering what a pale redhead and obvious foreigner was doing there with a fully packed touring bike. I aroused much more curiosity there than in other countries I have been cycling in. I would rather guess that it is a general cultural thing in Turkey than being related to köfte.

Comment: Look for "dukanis" - დუქანი - They're not quite the same but they're less fancy than "restaurants". Or look for bakeries. You can get pies with either beans (lobiani), cheese, or meat. In spring and summer you can get the best tomatoes in the world. I would get local bread (tonis puri and also some other names) and local cheese. Buy from the grannies rather than shops and ask for village yoghurt, village eggs, etc. I haven't been for over a decade so I don't know how much has changed...

Answer (score 4):

In Azerbaijan these would be just "kafe"s ("çayxana"s too to some extent, but they focus more on tea). They are usually located off the big streets and have names written in awful graphic design. You would see images of the foods printed on the front of those kafes. Here's e.g. my [favorite such place](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%C5%9Eu%C5%9Fa+m%C9%99tb%C9%99xi/@40.4167426,49.8397636,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipMF_4-Bq0bBxOS9FDpzYePega6yB7AFlcEz92WV!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipMF_4-Bq0bBxOS9FDpzYePega6yB7AFlcEz92WV%3Dw226-h100-k-no!7i4640!8i2048!4m7!3m6!1s0x4030874da90688e1:0xb6e6b596db72a0e5!8m2!3d40.4167095!4d49.839527!10e5!16s%2Fg%2F11j1zb1260?entry=ttu). Another good indication of such places is the sound of the dices and violent placement of pieces on the board coming from men playing backgammon.

The prices have gone up but you can get a hot meal, salad/pickles and a cold drink (ayran/doğramac) in such kafes for usually around 7 AZN (4$) in Baku (should be cheaper in countryside).